# creating an object in a driver class for a heap sort implementation

Tags: java, sorting, heap, heapsort

I'm implementing a HeapSort class so it orders the entire list at once using an addAll method and re-stores the elements ordered in heap into the list. This the driver program for the HeapSort class. Why am I not able to create a new HeapSort object? What i mean by that is, when I try to create the heapsort object, I get errors saying "HeapSort is a raw type. references to generic type HeapSort should be parameterized." and also errors like "constructor HeapSort(Integer[]) is undefined."
What do these mean? why cant i make this object?

```
/*demonstrates the HeapSort class so it orders the
 * entire list at once using addAll method and re-stores
 * the elements ordered in heap into the list*/
public class HeapDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a list of integer objects
        Integer[] data = {4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3};
        //display elements in list before sorting
        System.out.println("Elements in the list before sorting:");
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();

            //create object for HeapSort class
            HeapSort first = new HeapSort(data);

            //display elements in list after sorting
            System.out.println("\nElements in the list after sorting:");
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) 
                System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Here's my HeapSort class:

```
/**
 * HeapSort sorts a given array of Comparable objects using a heap.
 * 
 * @author Java Foundations
 * @version 4.0
 */
public class HeapSort<T>
{
    /**
     * Sorts the specified array using a Heap
     *
     * @param data the data to be added to the heapsort
     */

    ArrayHeap heap;

    public void HeapSort(T[] data) 
    {
        ArrayHeap<T> temp = new ArrayHeap<T>();

        addAll(data);
        // copy the array into a heap 
        /*
         * for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            temp.addElement(data[i]);*/

        // place the sorted elements back into the array 
        int count = 0;
        while (!(temp.isEmpty()))
        {
            data[count] = temp.removeMin();
            count++;
        }
    }
    //accepts a list of elements and stores all elements into heap
    private void addAll(T[] list) {
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
            heap.addElement(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Without any kind of error messages, we can't really say.

Comment: @Mureinik sorry i updated that now

Comment: @JoeC Sorry I've updated that now

Comment: `constructor HeapSort(Integer[]) is undefined` means, well, that this constructor is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Help us help you - share `HeapSort`'s code (at least the class and constructor(s) definition)

Comment: @JoeC Its defined in the HeapSort class

Comment: @Mureinik sorry i'm adding that now

Comment: So is `HeapSort` a generic type? Does it have a constructor that takes an array as a parameter?

Comment: @LewBloch In the HeapSort class you can see that it has a constructor that takes an array as paramter

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a constructor that takes an array. Method names should begin with a lower-case letter and definitely should not be named the same as the class. Constructors don't have return types.

```
public void HeapSort(T[] data)
```

Not a constructor.

Comment: but now my error says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HeapSort.addAll(HeapSort.java:38)
 at HeapSort.<init>(HeapSort.java:21)
 at HeapDemo.main(HeapDemo.java:18)

Comment: why does that happen when i run the driver program?

Comment: `addAll` makes calls through a reference, or pointer, variable, `heap`. If `heap` is `null`, it must not have been initialized to any other value. Was it initialized to any other value?